# track user choice for Push Notification [allow/don't]

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

When an application need to register for push notification (UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes) a popup show Allow/Don't choice.

Is there a way to track *when* the user take this choice ?

Because the solution:

```
NSUInteger rntypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

is fine, but until the user touch something it's NO by default. I should only check this config *after* the user make a choice.

The consequence is that in my EasyAPNS server most of the application are in 'disabled' mode until the user relaunch them (because the second time the correct config will be pushed to my sever). So with the first launch the real choice of the user is probably not taken into account (if you accept really rapidly, before my app register to EasyAPNS then your choice is reflected back on the server at first launch)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no way to determine whether the allow pop-up has been shown. I rely on user defaults to keep track of this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    BOOL didRegisterForPush = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didRegisterForPush"];
    if (!didRegisterForPush) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"didRegisterForPush"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    // .. send deviceToken to server
}
```

Now you can determine the authorization state using:

```
- (PushAuthorizationStatus)pushAuthorizationStatus
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types) {
        return kPushAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
    }
    BOOL didRegisterForPush = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didRegisterForPush"];
    if (didRegisterForPush) {
        return kPushAuthorizationStatusDenied;
    }
    return kPushAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined;
}
```

Using this you can send the `NotDetermined` state to the server instead of `Denied`.

Answer (score 2):

Under iOS 8 and later the procedure is a little different. In iOS 8 the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` method was replaced by `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`.

*However* `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` *always returns `YES`* if the app attempted to register for notifications, regardless of whether the user actually allowed them or not.

To determine whether the user actually allowed notifications, use the function provided by @Lefteris [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441181/1161906):

```
- (BOOL)pushNotificationsEnabled {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType types = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];
        return (types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);
    }
    else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        return (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` does not always return `YES`. Returns: YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and received its device token or NO if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied by the user.