# Check if push enabled or location enabled ios sdk

Tags: ios, push-notification, cllocationmanager, xcode7.2

I'm using following code to detect these 2 (Push Notifications and Location Services)

```
    [postvars setObject:([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])?@"true":@"false" forKey:@"locationServicesEnabled"];

    BOOL pushEnabled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
    [postvars setObject:(pushEnabled)?@"true":@"false" forKey:@"pushServicesEnabled"];
```

But the issue is I'm always getting true for both even If I tap Don't allow when prompted in the app. Also in settings app I checked that Location is set to Never and notifications subheading shows off. What's wrong with this code ? can anyone guide me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checking `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` is not enough.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    [postvars setObject:@"true" forKey:@"locationServicesEnabled"];

}
```

**For Notifications** Check this awesome [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28441181/988169)

```
BOOL pushEnabled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
[postvars setObject:(pushEnabled)?@"true":@"false" forKey:@"pushServicesEnabled"];

UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
   {
    [postvars setObject:@"false" forKey:@"pushServicesEnabled"];
}
```

Comment: for your information the docs says

/*
 *  locationServicesEnabled
 *
 *  Discussion:
 *      Determines whether the user has location services enabled.
 *      If NO, and you proceed to call other CoreLocation API, user will be prompted with the warning
 *      dialog. You may want to check this property and use location services only when explicitly requested by the user.
 */

Comment: ideally it should return false. Don't you think ?

Comment: Yes. Agree with your points. It must return false. Have you tried in device?

Comment: added your code and it worked but still no luck with Push. Thanks

Comment: For notification, try to check `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` as written in my updated answer.

Comment: got the answer from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441007/checking-push-notification-registration-isregisteredforremotenotifications-not

Comment: Yes, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28441181/988169) is very useful. I have added the reference of same in my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

***Check if Push notifications Enabled or Location Services Enabled:***

***Push Notifications:***

From iOS above 8.0 it registers the device and provides a Token even if the user opts out from pushes.

but, pushes are not presented to the user when the push is sent, so it will return `true`.

```
- (BOOL)isPushNotificationsEnabled {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType types = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];
        return (types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);
    }
    else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        return (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert);
    }
}
```

`enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is deprecated since iOS8.

To check remote notifications status in iOS8 you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

Check the answers here: [detect “Allow Notifications” is on/off for iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111644/detect-allow-notifications-is-on-off-for-ios8)

Read docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/currentUserNotificationSettings

Also read the thread here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16958

***Location Services:***

Needs to check for both `locationServicesEnabled` and `authorizationStatus` like,

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
   //Enabled
}
```