# Swift ios checking if user has enabled notifications always return true

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I am trying to check if the user has enabled remote notifications for my app but it always return true even if I disable/uninstall my app.

I am checking with this code:

```
if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications == false {
    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications()
    print("Notifications is off")
} else {
   print("Notifications is on")
}
```

But this will always run: `print("Notifications is on")`

So how can I check if user has enabled notification for my app?

Comment: Even if a user denies or disabled notifications, the app is still registered.

Comment: My answer here is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28441181/312312

Answer (score 1):

```
    if let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings {
         if settings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
             print("is on!")
         }else{
             print("is off!")
         }
}else{
     print("is off")
}
```

This seems to work, not sure if its the right way?

Comment: @RomOne no its all there, try copy/paste it :)

Comment: Yep my mistake :) I'm not entirely sure, but here I think you are testing if the user has enable notification in general, not for your app specifically

Comment: @RomOne this didnt work either : / If I press deny it wont prompt me anymore

Comment: This is normal, you can ask for permission only once. And once you have asked, isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications will always be set to YES. In addition currentUserNotificationSettings return if user has a set on its notification in general, meaning that you still cannot know the notification setting for your app

Answer (score 0):

Actually this will always return `true`, it will return `false` only in the case the permission for remote notification were never asked. Meaning that once you have asked the user, not matter what he has answered, this will always return `true`.

The raison why is that when you ask permission, it registers directly the user (without even waiting his answer, you can check by putting breakpoints that the delegate is triggered before the answer of the user). Then if the user denied the permission, the device will still be registered but notifications won't show up until the user turn them on in general settings.

This is not a bug, Apple does this to avoid dev keep asking for permissions. So it's actually not possible to know if a user has accepted or denied permission :/

Comment: But how come certain apps show a popUp message sometimes telling me to enable notifications. Also check my answer bellow

Comment: They are some way to guess, but it can be tricky. and you won't be sure at all, it's just a guess. I'll try to find how I did that in previous work and post an update ;)